# How do I install MeshMixer on 14.10?

Tags: printing, 3d

I am trying to install MeshMixer 2.7 from their new [linux download page](http://www.meshmixer.com/linux.html). It was originally packaged for 14.04 but I'm running 14.10. When I run the .deb, it complains that it is missing the `libsuperlu3` package. It seems it became `libsuperlu4` with the 14.10 release.

I haven't found a ppa with `libsuperlu3` built for Utopic. Can I get the `libsuperlu3` debs from the Trusty repo and try install them? Or is there a way I can tweak the MeshMixer .deb to reference libsuperlu4 instead?

There isn't a 3D-printing tag yet - can someone with sufficient rep please add it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my tested solution that will work on any ubuntu (or debian) distro. This will download meshmixer 2.9 and dependencies, install it on a opt/ dir on your $HOME and create a meshmixer bin to run it. Doesn't need root access to install or run

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    PREFIX=$HOME/opt/meshmixer
    FILES=$HOME/Document*/meshmixer
    mkdir -p $PREFIX $FILES $HOME/bin
    cd /tmp
    
    for DEB in \
      http://openartisthq.org/debian/xenial64/meshmixer_2.9_amd64.deb \
      http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/b/boost1.54/libboost-date-time1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1_arm64.deb \
      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.54/libboost-system1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb \
      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.54/libboost-filesystem1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb \
      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.54/libboost-thread1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb \
      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cgal/libcgal10_4.2-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libk/libkml/libkml0_1.3.0~r864-2_amd64.deb \
      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/superlu/libsuperlu3_3.0+20070106-3_amd64.deb \
      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtwebkit-source/libqtwebkit4_2.3.2-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb \
      http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.3_amd64.deb \
    ; do
      DEBF=`basename $DEB`
      wget -q $DEB
      dpkg -x $DEBF $PREFIX
    done
    
    cp -va $PREFIX/usr/share/meshmixer/* $FILES/
    cat > $HOME/bin/meshmixer <<EOM
    #!/bin/bash
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib:$PREFIX/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$PREFIX/usr/lib:$PREFIX/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$PREFIX/opt/meshmixer/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    exec $PREFIX/opt/meshmixer/bin/meshmixer "$@"  &
    EOM
    chmod a+x $HOME/bin/meshmixer
```

Unfortunately the http://discreteform.com/linux.html deb download is not available anymore, so you'll need to google for meshmixer_2.9_amd64.deb (like I did) IF the first link ins't available at the time you read this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the [Meshmixer deb file](http://www.meshmixer.com/linux.html).
2. Install GDebi.
3. Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libsuperlu3 and download the amd64 version (don't worry about downloading any of the dependencies as they are available in the Utopic repo and will be handled by GDebi).
4. Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libsuperlu3-dev and download *its* amd64 version (again, ignoring dependencies).
5. Run GDebi.
6. Navigate to File -> Open and select the `libsuperlu3` deb file downloaded in step 3.
7. It should do a check and return "Status: All dependencies are satisfied" or "Status: Requires the installation of X packages." at the top. Both of these are a good sign. Make sure the Ubuntu Software Center and Synaptic Package Manager are closed. Click "Install Package".
8. Repeat steps 6 and 7 for the `libsuperlu3-dev` deb file downloaded in step 4.
9. Repeat steps 6 and 7 for the MeshMixer deb file.
10. From the terminal, run `meshmixer`. You can lock to launcher once it's running if you'd prefer to launch from there in future.

Note: Integration with the Ubuntu dash and other packaging details are currently being polished by the MeshMixer team and free software contributors. See http://meshmixer.com/forum/index.php?topic=2005.0 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for 15.10 x64:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/libboost-date-time1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb 
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/libboost-system1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb 
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/libboost-filesystem1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb 
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/libboost-thread1.54.0_1.54.0-4ubuntu3_amd64.deb 
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/libcgal10_4.2-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/libkml0_1.3.0~r864-2_amd64.deb 
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/libsuperlu3_3.0+20070106-3_amd64.deb 
sudo gdebi ~/Downloads/meshmixer_2.9_amd64.deb
```

All `*.deb` files can be found at `http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/{}/download`.

BTW: This is obviously a terrible hack, as these old packages could have security and bugginess issues. Autodesk: update your deb! - kthxbye

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu 15.10, but I also had to add ``exit 0`` on the start of ``/var/lib/dpkg/info/meshmixer.postinst`` so the package manager won't break.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the debs from https://packages.ubuntu.com (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libsuperlu3) and use those. You can use the command line `gdebi` to install them.

Note you probably need to get the ones matching the MeshMixer packages *bit, in this case the [amd64 64bit packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libsuperlu3/download). You will need a system running Ubuntu 64bit.

Comment: Thanks @Wilf! I've answered with fuller instructions as it was a non-trivial process.